# How to backup just a node?

Tags: nodes, backups

I need to backup just a node. Usually I get this by searching the info of the node in the database but I'm just wondering if the **backup and migrate module** could help to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could export it with [Node export](http://drupal.org/project/node_export) module.

> This module allows users to export nodes and then import it into another Drupal installation, or on the same site.
>
> Using this module you can save yourself a lot of time setting up new websites that have similar nodes to websites you've already made, migrating nodes to new Drupal versions, or between development/staging/production sites.

Answer (score 2):

You could potentially load a node and [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) it to file

e.g

```
$nid = 12;
$node = node_load($nid);
// This converts the node object to a string
$data = serialize($node);
// Now save the file
$filename = date("Y-m-d").'_node_backup_'.$nid.'.txt';
// Create the backups folder within the files folder.
$filepath = 'public://backups';
$uri = $filepath . '/' . $filename;
// Create the backup file.
file_prepare_directory($filepath, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY);
if (!file_exists($uri) && !file_unmanaged_save_data($data, $uri, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE)) {
  drupal_set_message("Failed to backup node");
}else{
  drupal_set_message("Successfully created backup of node");
}
```

It could then be loaded from file and [unserialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) with `unserialize($node);`